# Trouble getting NSUserDefaults storage method to appropriately update text label iOS

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, viewcontroller

I'm trying to use the NSUserDefaults class to hold a bunch of text label info. Specifically, I have a view with a button and a label. When the button is clicked, it takes the user to another view using the "modal" connection. In this second view, the user uses a slider to set a value. A single button shifts back to the first view upon clicking, also using the "modal" connection. I want to insert a piece of code so that when the user uses the slider on the second view and clicks the button, it updates the text label on the first view to the value of the slider.

This is the code I put under the button method in the second view:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"myValue" forKey@"myKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
_textLabelOnFirstView.text = [defaults stringForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Also, for the same view controller under the "viewDidLoad" method, I put the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NsUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
_textLabelOnFirstView.text = [defaults stringsForKey:@myKey"];
```

However, this is what happens: After I open the first view, I click the button to get to the second view. In the second view I slide the slider to 100, and then click the button. The button takes me back to the first view, but the label never updated, and does not say 100. If I close the app and reopen, the label is still wrong. However! If I click the button to go to second view, and then click the second view's button to get back to the first view (even without adjusting the slider), I now see the value of 100 in the text label.

Can anyone please suggest how to change my code so that the first view's text label is updated with the slider's value as soon as the user transitions from the second view back to the first? Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code... If you are only updating the label in viewDidLoad, then the current behavior is expected. ViewDidLoad will only be called once, you might be looking for viewDidAppear which will be called every time the view finishes a transition onto the screen. I would also suggest viewWillAprear, so that the value is updated before the transition happens.

Comment: Thanks so much Matt, I was unaware of those two methods, both of which solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt G pointed out, using ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad correctly solved my problem by being called each time the view appeared, instead of its first instance